# Counting number of positive value in a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on the following query and table

```
SELECT dd.actual_date, dd.week_number_overall, sf.branch_id, AVG(sf.overtarget_qnt) AS targetreach
FROM sales_fact sf, date_dim dd 
WHERE dd.date_id = sf.date_id
AND dd.week_number_overall BETWEEN 88-2 AND 88
AND sf.branch_id = 1
GROUP BY dd.actual_date, branch_id, dd.week_number_overall
ORDER BY dd.actual_date ASC;

ACTUAL_DATE WEEK_NUMBER_OVERALL  BRANCH_ID TARGETREACH
----------- ------------------- ---------- -----------
13/08/14                     86          1         -11 
14/08/14                     86          1          12 
15/08/14                     86          1        11.8 
16/08/14                     86          1         1.4 
17/08/14                     86          1        -0.2 
19/08/14                     86          1         7.2 
20/08/14                     87          1        16.6 
21/08/14                     87          1        -1.4 
22/08/14                     87          1        14.4 
23/08/14                     87          1         2.8 
24/08/14                     87          1          18 
26/08/14                     87          1        13.4 
27/08/14                     88          1        -1.8 
28/08/14                     88          1        10.6 
29/08/14                     88          1         7.2 
30/08/14                     88          1          14 
31/08/14                     88          1         9.6 
02/09/14                     88          1        -3.2
```

the "TargetReach" column shows whether target has been reach or not.
A negative value means target wasn't reached on that day. 
How can I get calculate the number of ROW with positive value for this query?

that will show something like:

```
TOTAL_POSITIVE_TARGET_REACH WEEK_NUMBER_OVERALL
--------------------------- ------------------
13                          88
```

I have tried to use CASE but still not working right.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want a single value across all three weeks, against the latest week; not a separate count per week?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use conditional aggregation:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select week_number_overall, sum(case when targetreach > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
from t
group by week_number_overall;
```

However, I would rewrite your original query to use proper `join` syntax.  Then the query would look like:

```
SELECT week_number_overall,
       SUM(CASE WHEN targetreach > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM (SELECT dd.actual_date, dd.week_number_overall, sf.branch_id, AVG(sf.overtarget_qnt) AS targetreach
      FROM sales_fact sf JOIN
           date_dim dd 
           ON dd.date_id = sf.date_id
      WHERE dd.week_number_overall BETWEEN 88-2 AND 88 AND sf.branch_id = 1
      GROUP BY dd.actual_date, branch_id, dd.week_number_overall
     ) t
GROUP BY week_number_overall
ORDER BY week_number_overall;
```

THe difference between a CTE (the first solution) and a subquery is (in this case) just a matter of preference.

Comment: Is there any performance issues when we use CTE and sub query? Which one is preferable?

Comment: @RGS . . . I believe in Oracle, subqueries and CTEs should produce essentially the same execution plan, but you should check on your particular query.  This is not true in all databases.  CTEs are more flexible than subqueries; I use both.

Comment: I took it one step forward: [gist](https://gist.github.com/drorata/bdfa45d1b8076daf493063838939decf)

Answer (score 2):

```
select sum( decode( sign( TARGETREACH ) , -1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 ) ) 
from ( "your query here" );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT WEEK_NUMBER_OVERALL, COUNT(*) TOTAL_POSITIVE_TARGET_REACH
FROM (your original query)
WHERE TARGETREACH >= 0
GROUP BY WEEK_NUMBER_OVERALL
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear, but I *think* the OP wants a single number; so `max(week_number_overall), count(*)` with no `group by`?

Answer (score 1):

Using decode(), sign() get both positive count & negative count.

```
drop table test;

create table test (
key number(5),
value number(5));

insert into test values ( 1, -9 );
insert into test values ( 2, -8 );

insert into test values ( 3, 10 );
insert into test values ( 4, 12 );

insert into test values ( 5, -9 );
insert into test values ( 6, 8 );
insert into test values ( 7, 51 );

commit;

select sig , count ( sig ) from
(
select key,  ( (decode( sign( value ) , -1 , '-ve' , 0 , 'zero' , 1 , '+ve' ) ) ) sig
from test 
)
group by sig



SIG  COUNT(SIG)             
---- ---------------------- 
+ve  4                      
-ve  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `HAVING` Clause

```
SELECT dd.actual_date, dd.week_number_overall, sf.branch_id, AVG(sf.overtarget_qnt) AS targetreach
FROM sales_fact sf, date_dim dd 
WHERE dd.date_id = sf.date_id
AND dd.week_number_overall BETWEEN 88-2 AND 88
AND sf.branch_id = 1
GROUP BY dd.actual_date, branch_id, dd.week_number_overall
HAVING AVG(sf.overtarget_qnt)>0
ORDER BY dd.actual_date ASC;
```